# Using regexes in ruby with a need to match lots of * and /

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to find strings with * and / using reg-exes, I am writing in Ruby.The reason for this need to find lots of * and / is that I am building a tokenizer for an language and there are multi-line comments that use the C style of multi-line comments (/*   */). I have the single line comments handled already.

Is there a way to use reg-ex without having to use the two foreword slashes to indicate some regular expression because I am finding it impossible to find my mistakes due to the insane amount of escaping. Or can someone give me advise on how to handle the escaping in a sane matter? I already tried writing the sequence first then escaping it.

Thank you for your time and advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick that might help is the `%r` literal:

```
%r{http://www\.google\.com}
```

I like to use pipes myself, when they're not in the regex.

```
%r|http://www\.google\.com|
```

You can also create new instances of Regexp via `Regexp.new` and pass a string.

Finally, you might also [look at `Regexp.quote`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-quote):

> Escapes any characters that would have special meaning in a regular expression. Returns a new escaped string, or self if no characters are escaped. For any string, `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(str))=~str` will be true.

Comment: Worth mentioning Regexp.quote too

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Nice, I didn't know about that method; I've added it to the answer.